# Pyplot pie chart bug with small values

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I try to plot an array of small values on a pie chart, but I get the following result:

```
values = [0.077, 0.028, 0.006, 0.149, 0.081]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.pie(values, startangle=90)
plt.show()
```

[image: Bug]

However, I just have to multiply these values by 10 to get the correct result:

```
values = [v*10 for v in values]
```

[image: Normal]

Any idea why this happens, and how to fix it?

(Note: I'm using Python 2.7, matplotlib 1.4.3, and I am running the script from a IPython notebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, but the expected behaviour. From the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie):

> Make a pie chart of array x. The fractional area of each wedge is given by x/sum(x). **If sum(x) <= 1, then the values of x give the fractional area directly and the array will not be normalized.**

It doesn't look like [`pyplot.pie`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pie) has an option to normalise the array automatically for arrays with sums less than 1, so if you want to fill the pie chart, I suggest you normalise them yourself (or just multiply them by some number to ensure the sum is `> 1`, as you have already found out).